# Force my client to use TLS1.2 to access my web application, if not then return an error message

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, security, tls1.2

TLS 1.0,1.1,1.2 are enabled in my web server now.
TLS1.0,1.1 cannot be disabled because I have a mobile app that will call my API through TLS1.0,1.1.
I would like to enforce my clients to use TLS1.2 to access my web portal, and if they don't, I would return an error message to them.
Is there a way to do it programmatically?

Both of my web application & mobile app are already in production and they are using same port 443.
Someone suggest me to clone my web application and host in another server that disabled TLS1.0,1.1. But I cannot change the link of my website & the API URL since they were already in production.

Comment: This is not really programming related and you should consult your network administrators. For Windows Server 2019 and above, you can disable legacy TLS versions per HTTPS binding, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/engineering/disable-legacy-tls as you wished. For older Windows releases, you will have to use a reverse proxy server such as nginx.

Comment: Thanks @LexLi, my server version is Window server 2012, would you please elaborate more on the older windows part? thank you

Comment: 1) Build a nginx box (typically on Linux VM or simply Docker/K8s) 2) configure `server` blocks on it to host your actual sites, and forward traffic to this IIS machine via `proxy_pass`. 3) Flip DNS records to cut off the traffic from IIS. New requests will land first on nginx and then proxy to IIS. On nginx you can disable legacy TLS versions per site. Again, find an expert in your team to assist. While the steps are not hard for most people, you do need to be careful in every steps as this is your production environment and you want to be secure.